# Как спрятать ссылку средствами JS

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно скрыть ссылку посредством JS. Много всяких вариантов нашел, но почему-то не один не работает.

Один из вариантов:
`<span class="my-link" data-url="http://google.com/">Ссылка</span>`

Добавляю в файл JS код и подключаю:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my-link').forEach(function(link) {
  link.onclick = function() {
    window.open(link.dataset.url); // Если хочешь открыть новую вкладку
    location.href = link.dataset.url; // Если хочешь перейти по ссылке в этой вкладке
  };
});
```

На выходе получаю

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function
```

Также пробовал такой вариант:

```
<span class="hidden-link" data-link="http://goo.gl">внешняя ссылка</span>
```

Добавляю в JS код:

```
function jslink() {
    $('.hidden-link').replaceWith(function(){
        return'<a href="'+$(this).data('link')+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a>';
    })
}
```

Движок Wordpress.

Comment: `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my-link')).forEach(function(link) { ...` или `[...document.getElementsByClassName('my-link')].forEach(function(link) { ...`

Comment: в каком браузере пробовал?

Comment: непонятно что ты имеешь ввиду под _спрятать ссылку_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.my-link');
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.onclick = function() {        
    window.open(link.dataset.url); // Если хочешь открыть новую вкладку
    location.href = link.dataset.url; // Если хочешь перейти по ссылке в этой вкладке
  };
});
```

Comment: Ошибок нет, но все равно как была ссылка ввиде текста, так и осталась, то есть нет возможности кликнуть по ссылке http://prntscr.com/tdxct7

Comment: У меня все "тыкаеться" и переходится. Мб я как то иначе понимаю вашу проблему?
https://codepen.io/lotus34rus/pen/GRodKWQ

Comment: В вашем примере все работает, но у меня на сайте ссылка не активна. Может ли это быть из-за Jquery?
Вот пример страницы https://finansanswer.ru/mikrokredity/zajmy-moj-kapital/ тестирую снизу ссылку с анкором "Ссылка". В гугл Консоли нет ошибок

Comment: Сомневаюсь,что дело в jquery. В скрипте то тут чистый JS.
А сам скрипт у вас ниже чем код шаблона?

Comment: Сам скрипт у меня в хедере подключается.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда его спустить "вниз". Вы в коде обращаетесь к DOM дереву, а оно в этот момент мб еще не "готово"

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!